# Hi guys, my columns do not centre, any ideas?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, list

my columns are not behaving and are all squashed to the left, i've tried overriding the col-2 to set no margins or flex and nothing works, any ideas? thanks.

```
<li>
 <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>More<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($Ranking as $post): ?>
  
      <div class="row" style="margin: 0px 30px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            <div class="col-2">
             <h4 style="font-weight: 500;"><a 
             href="/single_page_main.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?> 
             </a></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="col-2">
             <h4><?php echo html_entity_decode($post['body']); ?></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4">
             <img src="<?php echo '/assets/images/' , 
             $post['image']; ?>">
            </div>

            <div class="col-4">
             <a href="/player_profile.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>"><div class="">Profile</div> 
             </a>
            </div>

         </div>
       </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
  </li>

 </ul>

    $(function() {
    var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
    this.el = el || {};
    this.multiple = multiple || false;

    var links = this.el.find('.link');
    links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, 
    this.dropdown)
    }
    Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
    var $el = e.data.el;
        $this = $(this),
        $next = $this.next();
    $next.slideToggle();
    $this.parent().toggleClass('open');
    if (!e.data.multiple) {
   $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
    };
    }   
    var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
    });
```

The above is the jquery accordion code used to show the ul content on click, however all the conent within this has been moved to the left and none of it centres even with overriding css styles or html code, any ideas? thanks.

```
.accordion {
width: 100%;
margin: 30px auto 20px;
background: #FFF;
max-width: 800px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.accordion .link {
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
color: #4D4D4D;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 700;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

Above is the CSS, thanks.

I get this
[image]

I'm trying to achieve this
[image]

Comment: Can you post the CSS that goes with this, please? And also, a screenshot showing the problem, and something showing what you're trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular i've added it all in now, thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you're using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com)? Which version?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i'm using 3.3.7

Comment: As far as I know version 3.3.7 doesn't have classes like `col-2` or `col-4`. That's only present in newer versions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "Hi Guys" is not a relevant component of a good question title on any support platform.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes you were right i've since updated the CDN and we now have lift off. Thanks for your help appreciate it :)

Comment: would anyone know how I can change the JS so that the accordion is closed by default? thanks